# DropDownList Displays Upward

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, list.selectedvalue

I believe this is a simple fix but haven't come across it.

My dropdownlist will display the options upward rather than downward if the empty newListItem is `.Selected = true`.

Is there a way to make the list drop downward instead?

My SQL statement orders by alphabet (so Computer is on top).

```
OracleDataAdapterAds1.Fill(DsAds, "TABLE NAME")
CategoryListBox.DataSource = DsAds
CategoryListBox.DataMember = "TABLE NAME"
CategoryListBox.DataBind()
Dim newListItem As ListItem
newListItem = New ListItem("", "")
newListItem.Selected = True
CategoryListBox.Items.Add(newListItem)
```

FYI - If `.Selected = false` they display downwards

When it is upward:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the selected item is the last one in the list. Insert the item on top

```
CategoryListBox.Items.Insert(0, newListItem);
```

Also, depending on your case, it's not a good idea to insert an emtpy item, especially when the control is databound.
You can leave the listbox unselected like this:

```
CategoryListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Wow you are awesome! I saw examples like this one before, at least the first code but not the -1 so I really appreciate the quick answer!